# What does contain mean in [dcl.constexpr]/3

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++14, constexpr

In [dcl.constexpr]/3 (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3), what does **contain** mean in "or a compound-statement that does not **contain**"?

For example:

```
constexpr int f(bool b) {
     return b ? ([]() { goto x; x: return 1; })() : 2;
}

int main() {}
```

Doesn't the compound-statement that makes up `f`:s body there contain the goto-statement?

I get no error message from Clang or GCC for that example.

Comment: @T.C. So `constexpr int f() { { goto lbl; } lbl: return 7; }` is fine? It's not accepted by any compiler I tested.

Comment: constexpr int f() { { goto lbl; } lbl: return 7; } is not fine, with contain they seem to mean even indirectly. In my example it seems to be too indirectly.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like it's not fine, which was my point: the simple answer (that it means "contain directly") doesn't seem to be correct, so your question still stands. Ah, I've just seen that you raised this issue yourself on `std-discussion`. It looks like we're in agreement.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use this function in a `constexpr` context, you will get the appropriate error:

```
constexpr int f(bool b) {
     return b ? ([]() { goto x; x: return 1; })() : 2;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(f(true)==2, "");    
}
```

> non-literal type 'const (lambda at main.cpp:2:18)' cannot be used in a
>   constant expression

Eliminating the lambda but keeping the goto will given an error as well:

```
constexpr int g() { goto x; x : return 1; }

constexpr int f(bool b) {
     return b ? g() : 2;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(f(true)==2, "");    
}
```

> ```
> main.cpp:1:21: error: statement not allowed in constexpr function
> constexpr int g() { goto x; x : return 1; }
>                     ^
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This was [CWG 2309](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2309.html), fixed in C++20 by the introduction of the "encloses" relation between statements. A statement that appears in the body of a lambda expression is not considered to be enclosed by the statement in which the lambda expression appears.

In C++23, all restrictions on what can be enclosed by a `constexpr` function will be abolished.